# how return only part of id with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, find, return-value

i'm running into an unusual situation in jQuery now.

I need to return only part of id. Let me explain it with an example

I have few label under divs like

```
<div id="x"><label id="price_1">...</label></div>
<div id="y"><label id="price_2">...</label></div>
<div id="z"><label id="price_3">...</label></div>
```

and jQuery goes like

```
var price_id= $("label#dont_know_what_to_write_here")
```

I need to return only 1 or 2 or 3 and put it in price_id , ignoring price_, can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you search by the parent element?

Comment: @bozdoz because the parents element have various id

Comment: it can be solved in a better way using custom attributes in html5

Comment: or you can use javascript native methods substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting, I would use the parent selector: `$('#x').find('label')`

For returning a value, I would recommend not putting a number in the id attribute. It would be much simpler to get the index of the element (assuming they are sibling elements), or set/get the data attribute:

```
<label data-id="1"></label>
$('#x').find('label').data('id'); // 1
```

Alternatively, you can use regular expression to get the digit from the string:

```
var price_id = $('#x').find('label').attr('id').replace(/\D/g, ''); // '1'
```

`\D` means not a digit; replaces non-digits with an empty string.

You could then convert it into a number if you want/need:

```
var price_id = Number(price_id);
```